# In CKEDITOR startupFocus : true, (For cursor at starting point) in onload not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

In chrome and IE - working!
[image: In Chorme and IE working fine]

In firefox - not working!! (cursor at end )
[image: In fire fox cursor at last]

I need to set ckediter cursor at staring position, i used `startupFocus : true,`  config its working fine in chrome and IE but not working in firefox..

my code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'MessageArea',
 {   
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>views/js/filemanager/index.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>views/js/filemanager/index.html',
    filebrowserWindowWidth : '800',
    filebrowserWindowHeight : '120',
    height                  : 140,
    toolbar                 : 'Basic',
    startupFocus : true

 }
 );
```

How to fix this ????

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this :

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(event) {
    var editor = event.editor;
    if(typeof(editor) !== 'undefined') {
       editor.focus();
       var element = editor.document.getBody()
       var range = editor.createRange();
       if(range) {
          range.moveToElementEditablePosition(element, false);
          range.select();
       }
    }
});
```

- My jsFiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/4WegG/13/
- Documentation : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-startupFocus

Comment: what is the reason to not use my version?

Comment: Because you don't check variables.

Comment: it isn't needed either to check this variables that you are checking. 
Because when the instanceReady is called the editor can't be undefined.. this should be a bug in the ckeditor.. Besides that if a range that you create, that isn't related with anything, doesn't work this would be also a bug within the ckeditor. I think that it's bad practice to check things without trowing error. Because neither the programmer, neither the client will know that somethings happens. Or that something went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First of all.. It's not that it isn't working. because if you read the documentation: 
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-startupFocus
It doesn't say that is sets the focus to the start of the document!

It only Sets the focus, and if i'm right it's standard browser behaviour of mozilla to place it at the end of an editable field.

now to anwser your question.

this fiddle will provide a way to focus directly on the start of the body element: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4WegG/3/